# IntelliJ IDEA - double quotes and letters changed to Unicode letters

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, encoding

I am facing a weird issue in IntelliJ that whenever I entered double quotes it will automatically converted into either 3 double quotes or sometimes it is converted to some Unicode letters.

For example, if I enter A after " then the text would change into something shown in the image.

[image]

I am using macOS 10.13 High Sierra. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as a little nit-pick, *all* letters are Unicode letters. But don't worry, I think I know what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: In windows helps me this solution: [enter link description here](https://superuser.com/questions/122625/apostrophes-and-double-quotes-dont-show-up-until-i-type-the-next-letter)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and the problem was not in IntelliJ IDEA but in keyboard input source on MacOS.

**The reason of issue:** I was using "U.S. International - PC" keyboard on MacOS. When I changed it to "U.S." the issue was gone.

**Steps to solve the issue:**

1. Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Source tab
2. Click on + button -> add "U.S." input source (or "British")

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of IntelliJ IDEA is to saving you time by inserting a pair of quotes when you type the opening quote. This is controlled by Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys.

The funny characters appearing in your case may be due to some weird setting. Try going to Settings -> Keymap.

Comment: There is nothing weird in Keymap, I even set it to default settings.